# nodejs - how to handle payment

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment

**Background:**

I am working on making nodejs function for payment using `stripe`.

My clients would have their own reward point, which can turn into cash dollar for payment

**Current Design**

Customer Table(mySQL)

```
-id: string(primary key)
-rewardPoints: int
```

Therefore I am working on 2 api seperately.

```
/transaction/debit-points 
   -this api is used to debit the reward point of clients when they want to turn it into cash dollar(debit the rewardPoints in Customer table)

/payment
   -this api will use stripe api to handle some credit card payment etc
```

**Example**
Let's say 100 reward points can turn into $1 cash dollar

Customer A is going to settle payment which is $200.
Customer A have 1000 reward points and want to turn all of it into cash dollar in this payment.

At first, I will use `/transaction/debit-points` to debit all 1000 reward points for the customer, and then use `/payment` to settle the payment.

```
1. /transaction/debit-points
2. /payment (run if /transaction/debit-points is successful)
```

If `/payment` fails, I want to reverse the effect of `/transaction/debit-points`, is it possible to do it in nodejs?

Or is there any better way?

Comment: Maybe better the other way around, subtract the amount of reward dollars from the Stripe payment, then. wait until Stripe is confirmed OK before finishing up the transaction by deducting the points from the db. This makes it a one-way street where you abort the transaction if Stripe fails. But: What about security. If the points come from the frontend or can be manipulated on the frontend, users can get away without paying. So remember to ONLY process reward data from the backend.

Comment: @anatolhiman according to your suggestion, what to do if deducting the points from the db fails? This means Stripe payment is successful but the db shows no deducting occur